# Developing for accessibility and I am being told <li> "List item does not have a <ul>, <ol> or role="list" parent element"

Tags: html, css, accessibility

Wondering what I am missing here.  We are overhauling a site for a client who wants to make sure everything is compliant and I am getting an error that I can't seem to solve.  I need to mention the source of the warning is a 3rd service that scans the pages of the site and presents issues in a report.

The error is this:

```
List item does not have a <ul>, <ol> or role="list" parent element
```

It is referencing this line (and all the others in the list like it:

```
<li id="get_started-scroll-button" class="scroll-button" data-element="get_started"></li>
```

This is the HTML.  I recently added the `role` value to the `ul` to see if that would help but it did not.  I get a warning about all the `li` in this list, and in others like it on other pages

```
...
<div class="col-12">
  <div class="container medium-font" style="margin:0px auto;">
    <ul class="scroll-subnav-list" style="list-style:none none;margin: 0;padding:0;float:none;" role="list">     
      
        <li id="overview-scroll-button" class="scroll-button scroll-button-container-first-el" data-element="overview">
          overview
        </li>
      
        <li id="resources-scroll-button" class="scroll-button scroll-button-container-els" data-element="resources">
           resources
        </li>
      
        <li id="get_started-scroll-button" class="scroll-button scroll-button-container-els" data-element="get_started">
           get started
        </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
...
```

What am I missing that would resolve the issue it is warning me about?

Comment: Who gives you the warning? https://validator.w3.org doesn't give me that with your code.

Comment: @SteeveDroz Oh sorry I should have mentioned that. It is a 3rd party service that scans the page, I will update the question to include that information

Comment: Is this tool up to date? There are many tools who do this job, so maybe switch to a more reliable one?

Comment: Which 3rd Party Service? And why do you trust that 3rdParty service if it gives you an error that the official HTML Validation Service of the WWW-Consortium doesnt see as an error?

I cant see any errors in your code neither.

Either the markup youre validating isnt the markup youre showing or the validator is giving a false positive.

If you want to validate HTML Structure https://validator.w3.org/ is the source of truth.

Comment: It isn't my decision what to use, I just have to work with it.  I guess I asked this question because I felt the need to push back on a lot of these issues but wanted to make sure I was correct in that this is valid HTML and I wasn't missing anything.

Comment: The only warning I see on W3C validator is that the role attribute you've added to ul is unnecessary. I suppose you could remove the attributes from the ul and see if your validator picks things up as an error and if not, slowly reintroduce them to see what the problem is (in their view).

Comment: @RockwellRice This doesn't sound like something a tool would get wrong, are you sure there isn't a stray `<li>` somewhere, some strange JS magic happening (is this the HTML source or the state of the application during testing in your example, bear in mind something as simple as adding `role="presentation"` via JS would break the semantics). Do you have a page we can check against as **I highly doubt** a tool would make such a simple mistake. Especially as the referenced line does not actually match any of the examples I have a feeling there is a stray `<li>`.

Comment: @GrahamRitchie The referenced line does match the id of the last <li> in my shared code.  That is the line it is mentioning, The text gets added dynamically so that is why they do not reference it in their warning.  I had the same doubt, as it seems such an obvious thing.  But I am sure there is not a stray or anything as it mentions specific elements and these have ids on them so I know what they are talking about, and the HTML I shared it taken directly from inspecting the page.

Comment: No problem then, just a very strange error to get and it not be true! In that case ignore it....and get a different piece of software to test with! 

Comment: Could it be that there is a weird invisible character between the `ul` and `li`?

Comment: @selfthinker No I do not think so.  There is nothing in the HTML at all, and this same error gets returned on other occurrences of this list, which we use for a mid page scroll nav.  So that space would mean that it just happens to be on like 5 other occurrences, which I just can't believe is what is going on, and I have inspected this quite a bit to make sure it is not something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the official W3C validator doesn't see any error, your code is fine. If your third party validator sees errors, I suggest you approach them via their Q&A or bug report website and asks them why they think it's wrong.

As you (obviously) noticed, the error is inconsistant, because the said line *does* have a `<ul>` parent. It is a bug on your 3rd party service side.

Comment: thanks, this is what I have suspected, I guess I just wanted to make sure I wasn't missing something I was unaware of.  I appreciate the response here.

Comment: A pleasure! Good luck with that 3rd party service!

Answer (score 3):

I know this has already been answered and accepted, but this seems relevant so I'm planting it here for future reference:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/list-style#accessibility_concerns

> Safari will not recognize an unordered list as a list in the accessibility tree if has a list-style value of none.

Comment: Thanks I will look into this and see if it helps out.

Comment: While Safari is stupid in not treating lists with list-style of none as a real list, with regards to how a screen reader announces it, it does not affect the validity of the html code and should not affect a scanning tool.  But it's a nice catch, @ray, seeing the list-style:none in the original code.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, since it references an actual solution.